# Dump Query to CSV with Column Aliases

Tags: mysql

I have a bunch of queries that I would like to **dump directly to CSV**.  Everything works great EXCEPT there is **no option to include the column names** from the query (not necessarily the same as the underlying table column names).  From looking around, it appears that **doing a union with the column names** is the only way to do what I want.  My problem is:

**How can I programmatically get the column names from my query?**

The column names are not the same as the underlying table, so I cannot use the Information Schema.

Please let me know if you have any ideas or a better way to accomplish what I'm doing!

Thanks!

Comment: Do you know things about your query in any programmatic way already?  If so, it's a lot easier to handle structured "field" information than parse the queries for 'AS ...,' strings, though a regexp might help: "\s+AS\s*([a-zA-Z0-9_])," but I doubt it'll be fast and it might not work with all the queries.

Comment: Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018316/sql-select-csv-file
or http://lifeboysays.wordpress.com/2012/06/23/mysql-how-to-export-data-to-csv-with-column-headers/
(google search)

Answer (score 0):

There's an article here:

http://giantdorks.org/alain/export-mysql-data-into-csv-or-psv-files/

That talks about sending SELECT output directly to a file and then modifying the text until it becomes a valid csv file.  That seems to support column headers from the select statement.