# SQL SELECT --> csv file

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL command that I need to save as a csv file with column headers:

```
mysql > SELECT  a.last_name, a.first_name, username, is_active, graduation
        FROM auth_user a
        INNER JOIN 
            userprofile_userprofile u
            ON a.id = u.user_id
        WHERE a.id>39 AND a.is_active=1 ORDER BY last_name
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not commiting any syntactical mistake this should work:

```
SELECT 'LastName', 'FirstName', 'Username', 'IsActive', 'Graduation'
UNION ALL
SELECT a.last_name, a.first_name, username, is_active, graduation
INTO OUTFILE 'yourFile.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
FROM auth_user a
INNER JOIN  userprofile_userprofile u
ON a.id = u.user_id
WHERE a.id>39 AND a.is_active=1
ORDER BY last_name
```

MySQL won't allow you to add column headers so you can hard code them in a union.

You can also check the `SELECT ... INTO` syntax [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select-into.html).

Comment: There were mentions of people using UNIONS as you have outlined here, but one must take care to optimize the query, otherwise a union against a large dataset may cause issues.

Comment: Right, I meant a `UNION ALL`, actually. However, why would adding a single record cause issues? Can you please clarify or provide any example or documentation link? Thanks.

Comment: "would adding a single record cause issues?". Sorry I don't understand the question. There are no records being added only selected.

Comment: I mean adding a single record to the result set generated by the `select` statement, not actually an insert statement.

Comment: Took me a few minutes to find the source, it's simply a comment to a posted solution. http://jasonswett.net/blog/how-to-get-headers-when-using-mysqls-select-into-outfile/

Comment: Well, this person added a dervied table to solve this issue and that's why it will be slow.

Comment: Ah makes sense. +1 in this case as the UNION shouldn't have an adverse impact on performance.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that MySQL does not [natively support](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=34992) the ability to include column headers in an export. A simple google search returned this [article](http://www.youdidwhatwithtsql.com/add-column-headers-mysql-outfile/911) which uses stream edit to add columns to an export file.

You may also want to read this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262924/how-to-export-dump-a-mysql-table-into-a-text-file-including-the-field-names-a) (and accepted solution) as it appears to be another option.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `INTO OUTFILE 'file_name' export_options`?

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Answer (score -1):

you can simply use  BCP command, in which case you have to enable the xp_cmdshell if you are using SQL mangement studio.

Here is an example

```
DECLARE    @bcpCommand varchar(2000)

SET @bcpCommand = 'bcp "SELECT * FROM users" queryout "c:\dump.csv" -U USERNAME -P PASSWORD -c'

EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcpCommand
```

Note that the csv file is located in the server where the database is hosted.

Comment: Note that author needs an answer for MySQL not MSSQLServer